# limit point of closure of complement

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is NOT open. Let $A$ be the set of limit points of closure of complement of $S$. That is, $A = lp(cl(S^{c}))$. Can $A \cap S$ be empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S$ is not open, then $S^c$ is not closed. Thus, it does not contain all its limit points, that is, $lp(S^c) \not \subseteq S^c$. Since the limit points of a set remain the same upon taking closure, we have $lp(S^c) = lp(cl(S^c)) = A$, so combining the two we get $A \not \subseteq S^c$. But "$A$ is not contained fully in $S^c$" is just saying "$A$ intersects with $S$", so we get $A \cap S \not = \emptyset$.